# Inline markup blocks cannot be nested. Only one level of inline markup is allowed. MVC RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, grid, telerik

I one one modal window with telerik grid inside. But i need to render images in my grid so as i understand i cant use @ twice. Here is blog post about this issue [Link](http://blogs.telerik.com/xamlteam/posts/11-01-27/mvc3-and-grid-hierarchy.aspx)

Can someone assist me please.

My Code

```
@{  Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("images")
    .Title("Select an Image")
    .Content(@<text>

@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("AjaxComboBox66")
            .AutoFill(true)
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.PhotoFolders, "ID", "Name"))
            .Filterable(filtering => filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.StartsWith))
            .HighlightFirstMatch(true)
            .ClientEvents(events => events
                .OnChange("onChange")
            )
      )

      @(Html.Telerik().Grid<AjaxImages>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.ID))
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Template(
          @<text>
               <img src='@item.Url' /> 
//Here is my error. I need helper function
           </text>

).Title("Picture");

  })

                              .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetImages", "UserProducts"))

                      .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true))
                      .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
                          .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true).PageSize(20).Total(100).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric))
                      .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
                      .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(false))
                      .EnableCustomBinding(true)

                      .Footer(true))
              </text>)
    .Width(400)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)


    .Render();
}
```

My GetImages function return me json with "ID" and "URL".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In these situations the MVC Razor helper function can be used.
Create the helper function with the grid control definition, in this case `RenderGrid()`.

```
@helper RenderGrid()
{
     @(Html.Telerik().Grid<AjaxImages>()
     .Name("Grid")
     .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.ID))
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Template(
         @<text>
             <img src='@item.Url' /> 
         </text>
         ).Title("Picture");
     })
     .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetImages", "UserProducts"))
}
```

Call the helper function inside the window's content definition. The helper functions can be called multiple times if needed.

```
    @{Html.Telerik().Window()
      .Name("images")
      .Title("Select an Image")
      .Content(
       @<text>
          @RenderGrid()
       </text>)
      .Width(400)
      .Draggable(true)
      .Modal(true)
      .Visible(false)
      .Render();
}
```

Comment: Almost done, please check both screenshots. I dont get any error but image <td> is empty. I tried to render as text, my ajax is working. Do you know why i dont get my images?  http://prntscr.com/9ix3a  http://prntscr.com/9ix3x

Comment: You are using the ajax binding and therefore need to use the client side template, instead of the server binding mode template. Try this:
`columns.Bound(c => c.ID).ClientTemplate("<img alt='<#= ID #>' src='<#= Url #>' />").Title("Picture");`

Answer (score 2):

In previous MVC `@helper` was used as a workaround for inability to **nest** `@<text>` tags.
But in MVC CORE `@helper` is omitted. Read more here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715